# Spring Data REST return entity after create/update using projection

Tags: spring-data-rest, projection, spring-rest

Spring Data REST has 2 properties (spring.data.rest.return-body-on-create, spring.data.rest.return-body-on-update) that are apparently true by default.

These properties make Spring return the submitted entity after create/update using POST/PUT/PATCH.

What I want is that the returned entity uses a projection to return its data so I tried submitting to this URL: http://localhost:8080/MYAPP/api/persons?projection=personProjection for new entities using POST and to this URL: http://localhost:8080/MYAPP/api/persons/1?projection=personProjection for old entities using PUT and PATCH.

All trials failed and I got the following exception: "Target bean of type com.sun.proxy.$Proxy231 is not of type of the persistent entity (com.test.entities.Person)!: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy231"

According to this question: [After upgrade from Spring Boot 1.5 to 2.1 we get Target bean of type com.sun.proxy.$Proxy is not of type of the persistent entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55404966/after-upgrade-from-spring-boot-1-5-to-2-1-we-get-target-bean-of-type-com-sun-pro)
It seems that what I was trying to do was possible in older version of Spring Data REST.

So is this a bug ?

Or is there a workaround for this behavior without having to get the entity again in another back-end call or creating a custom controller for submissions ?

I am using Spring Boot v2.2.6.RELEASE

Thanks

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1213 it's a bug